# "He is 80 years young"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

I've seen statements like "He is 80 years young" in many places. Also, I know that it means the same as

> He is 80 years old.

Now, why do people use **'young'** instead of **'old'** if it means the same? Or am I entirely misinformed and the statement is actually invalid?

Comment: Related somewhat: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47465/why-how-old-are-you-not-how-young-are-you/47469#47469

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a *<del>pun</del>* humorous way to tell that you are *still* young! I myself have used it a couple of times.

This simply means that the person is still energetic at that age and feels or appears *'young'*. Imagine a conversation:

> *"He is 45 years old."*
>   *"Old? Look at his energy; he's 45 years young!"*

Note that here, *old* does not mean having wrinkles or being on the verge of contracting *diseases associated with senility*! The word *old* here means [*of a particular age*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/old?q=old), so don't connect *old* with aged person *(बुज़ुर्ग)* when it is accompanied *by a number*.

Comment: But then, is it okay to use it literally ? Or is it only valid in a verbal context rather a written one ?

Comment: Added some more information to address your comment. I'd vote for using it *informally*.

Comment: _Informal_ you say ? All right. Thanks !

Comment: Someone who is 45 years _old_ is 5 years _old_**er** than when he was only 40 years _old_.  A child 45 inches _tall_ is 5 inches _tall_**er** than when he was only 40 inches _tall_.
Logically, then, someone who is 45 years _young_ would be 5 years _young_**er** than he was only 40 years _young_. Like every other form of euphemism, it's stupid.

Comment: Technically, if in "He is X years old", X is the number of years that have passed since he was born, then in "He is Y years young", Y *should* be the number of years that must pass before he dies.

Comment: You can't apply a literalistic meaning to a "X years young" statement. It is an idiom or wordplay with a well-known meaning.

Comment: It's a joke or *maybe* wordplay. One thing it *isn't* is a pun.

Comment: No, no, not a pun, no. What's the other thing which reads the same backwards as forwards? A _palindrome_...

Comment: @MontyHarder: If "someone who is 45 years *young* would be 5 years *young**er*** than he was only 40 years *young*", an elderly man 1.6m *tall* is 1dm *tall**er*** than when he was still 1.7m *tall*, right? Of course not. Someone who is 45 years *young* is 5 years *young**er*** than he will be when he is 50 years *young*. Which is exactly how the [flattery pointed out in another answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/75578/8456) is meant, because the focus is not on how many years have passed already, the focus is on the fact that the person still has many years ahead (or so one hopes).

Comment: I like to down vote as answer contains some unfamiliar language word.

Comment: @Danny I dont get that

Comment: What's that swirly word in your answer? Looks like italic styled sanscrit or thai. Is my computer going mad?

Comment: So, [wordplay is not a *pun?](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=pun)* @Martha

Comment: @rajakvk unfamiliar **to you!** No words then! :)

Comment: It's *Hindi* since the OP is Indian, I tried to explain that in a better way. **Note** that what I wrote in Hindi is **already** described in my answer in English. It was *additional* easier way for the OP. @KonradViltersten

Comment: @MaulikV Oh, that's Hindi... Didn't know that but now it makes sense. Please note that I didn't intend my remark as a complaint of any kind (if it came out as such, my apology). In fact, it's a neat flexibility (and given that Hindi speaking individuals are quite many, your target audience is probably wide, hehe.

Comment: @MaulikV, a pun is a specific kind of wordplay involving two words that sound alike and/or two different meanings of one word. (In actual practice, you can recognize a pun by the groans of the audience.)

Comment: @MaulikV அனைவருக்கும் தெரிந்த மொழியில் உரையாடுவது தான் நாகரீகம். Hope this text is unfamiliar **to you**. :-) 

If you use common language then your wonderful answer will reach still more audience.

Comment: @rajakvk writing entire sentence and writing a word, that too in brackets, is all different.

Answer (score 14):

[Years young<sup>1</sup>](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/years-young):

> describing how old one is in a humorous manner

Example:

> I will be fifty years young next year.

Avoid using it if you are serious. We're all getting older, so it would seem to make more sense to use "years old."

---

Exception: [Benjamin Button<sup>2</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Curious_Case_of_Benjamin_Button_%28film%29)

^ He would always say "years younger"

---

<sub>1. dictionary.reference.com</sub>
<sub>2. Wikipedia</sub>

Comment: Haha, +1 for the Benjamin Button reference. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

This is an illustration of [markedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markedness): a cognitive / linguistic phenomenon that is common to many languages, not just English.  Some adjective pairs are naturally asymmetrical:

- Young / old
- Short / tall
- Dumb / smart

You would normally ask how tall a person is.  On the other hand, if you ask "How short are you?", then it feels unusual, and it's no longer a neutral question: it's implying that you think the person is unusually short.

Similarly, if you ask "How young are you?", then it implies that you think someone is unexpectedly young.  If you say that "He is 80 years young", there is meta-information that the speaker thinks that the subject looks or acts younger than 80 years.

Answer (score 10):

It is a form of flattery. Instead of saying that the guy is old and infirm, the flatterer endeavors to imply that the flatteree is super-young for his age, sprite, full of energy, active, etc.

Comment: +1 because this is the real/common meaning behind it. Some will chuckle when saying it or hearing it, because it's clearly an exaggeration meant for flattery, but it's not a "joke" in the pure sense as others have suggested.

Comment: Yes, it is meant to be used to suggest that such a person looks (or feels) young.

Answer (score 3):

The word "old" essentially has two meanings.

One is simply a measure of age: How old are you? I am 5 years old.

In relative terms, a 5-year-old is considered young whereas an 80-year-old person is much nearer the end of his life and we would speak of him as being "old" in the sense of being elderly. The word has a lot of negative connotations and even teenagers refer to their 40-something parents as "old" in a dismissive, disrespectful way.

Using the expression "80 years young" is a way of flipping that around and suggesting that he is still very much vibrant and alive, the opposite of all the dreaded attachments of being "old".

Answer (score 1):

Used in a humorous sense. The speaker is trying to make light of age, which can sometimes be a difficult subject to approach. It is used to make an older person feel more at ease with his/her age.

Answer (score 0):

My 74 year dad used to call himself as "74 years young". He was full of curiosity and energy at 74.

So, it is okay to bend the rules of grammar and logic a bit, so long as the meaning comes through.

On the other hand, I would hesitate to say he is 80 years young for a stranger, in case the stranger feels I am not acknowledging or respecting his seniority.

Comment: What "rules of grammar and logic" are you referring to, specifically?

Comment: I am referring to the rules of grammar and logic other commentators have alluded to in this post. For example Zenadix's logical argument posted on Dec 11.

Answer (score 0):

You really have to be very careful about age because not everyone take the phrase well or may not understand what you are implying. I mentioned  the phrase " fifty years young" and I meant well. I tried to flatter them  but I don't think they took it to well. Then I asked a friend about the same phrase and she said, what it meant to her. Her meaning she gave of the phrase was , it meant a person was never born. Each person has there own interpretation. It all depends who you are addressing the phrase too.

Answer (score -1):

It's clearly a pun, but we can also interpret “he is 80 years young” as "he has been young for 80 years".